# how to detail more with gvisGeoMap in R with googleVis package?

Tags: r, google-visualization

I want to build a interactive map with the provinces of Spain. I use

```
G3 <- gvisGeoChart(data, "data.name", "Illiteracy",
option=list(region="ES", displayMode="regions", resolution="provinces", width=600, height=400))
```

but when I do that I get a Spain map with the communities. Is there any options to see the 50 provinces of Spain? Maybe with `gvisGeoMap()`?

Answer (score 1):

From the help of `gvisGeoChart`: Resolution "provinces" is

> Not supported for all countries; please test a country to see whether
>   this option is supported.

Probably for Spain that resolution is not supported.

Another explanation is that you need to use `displayMode="markers"` when you use `resolution="provinces"`